# Macro defined when targeting iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a macro defined when compiling for iOS ? 
I found `__APPLE__` but I need a macro defined only when targeting iOS.

In a broader view, I'm unable to find a web page describing those macro for Xcode, is there any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## define TARGET_OS_IPHONE

## define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

Found in TargetConditionals.h

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use one of the macros in `TargetConditionals.h`

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        // do iPhone work
#endif

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // do iPhone simulator work
#endif

#if TARGET_OS_MAC
        // do Mac work
#endif
```